# How to access the ceiling over an indoor swimming pool

Tags: ceiling, pool

How is the ceiling of an indoor swimming pool accessed, if repairs
 need to be done to anything up there?

[image: ceiling of indoor pool]

This is an indoor pool at a K-12 public school district. I need to take this speaker down and repair it. It is located over an irregular sloping floor between the shallow and deep end.

The ceiling lights can be replaced by the school district maintenance staff, because they are over the pool deck around the sides, so there is room to drive a vertical ceiling lift up to the side of the pool and get up there. However they don't have a way to access the middle of the ceiling out over the water.

,

This pool is drained every August for cleaning before the next school year begins in September, so there is a time of the year when the floor would be exposed without water.

This pool has a shallow end and a deep end, with a ramp that slopes
 down from the shallow to the deep, with a diving board off to the
 side, and so the slope itself is uneven from left to right across the
 slope.

Apparently some sort of platform is needed to level the slope so that
 a ladder or scaffolding could be utilized on top of it.

Also some sort of bracing is needed to keep the platform from sliding
 down the slope. The only thing I can think of, would be a long pole
 from the structure to the wall of the deep end.

A one-time-use wooden frame structure could be built, but it would be
 better if the platform could be adjusted and reused in different
 locations across the uneven pool floor.

Is there any sort of product or device that already exists, that is
 capable of doing this job?

Comment: Would it be okay to simply disconnect the wires to the speaker and then install a new one in a more convenient location?

Comment: This is called a Soundsphere. It is a spherical speaker with 360 degree dispersion. The best possible location for it is in the center of the ceiling of a room, which also minimizes echo and feedback.

Comment: use two extension ladders chained together at the top, to form an A frame whose apex is under the speaker. one ladder gets raised first to form a ramp, then the next to adjust height.

Answer (score 7):

Might want to check with your local equipment rental companies as they may have, or know where to direct you to get a transportable Cherry Picker. These machines are not as easily transported as a vertical scissor lift, but can be stationed on the side of the pool, or even in the pool and could reach the area that needs to be repaired. Most cherry picker's have stabilizing legs that can be deployed to help aid with uneven ground if placing inside the pool is needed.

[image: Cherry Picker]

Otherwise, Scaffolding can be installed in the pool with water or not. Make sure that the equipment is approved to be installed in water by the manufacturer, and the rental company, before taking action. You'll also want to consult with professionals what they suggest be done to make sure they are installed correctly, and securely. If putting them up in the water, you'll want to double check that they have been cleaned before installation.

[image: Scaffolding]

Comment: Scaffolding is the right solution. It can be easily erected directly under the speaker, and leveling legs are available to deal with the slope.

Comment: +1 for the cherry-picker, easiest and safest. A motorized manlift, similar to the cherry picker pictured, has 4 wheels and can be driven by the operator, no need to tow and no stabilizer jacks required. You would need a large door to get it in there though...

Comment: Scaffolding sounds a good idea - the two legs at the deeper end can be raised. Don't like the cherry picker - access from outside / into and out of the (empty) pool won't be easy, and its sheer weight may well compromise the pool bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reminded me of this photo I saw in a compilation titled “Why Women Live Longer Than Men”
This man is in a pool on an aluminum ladder barefoot with an electric drill
[image]

You don’t indicate how high the ceiling is from the pool floor  but little giant makes a ladder that may get you up there
[image]

See details at https://www.gamut.com/p/little-giant-step-ladder-21-ft-overall-ht-aluminum-11-ft-min-overall-ht-NTE0NDA5

Comment: If that pool is any like the ones I've been around, that ceiling is probably at least 25-30 feet tall above that particular spot in the pool.. I don't mind heights often but I think I'd mind that one

Comment: Well, if you were to fall, make sure you fall into the deep-end, feet first.